# How do I recover data from a Logical Volume on Linux after deleting it?

Tags: encryption, data-recovery, lvm, luks

Yesterday I was trying to shrink my Ubuntu partition with LUKS encryption to make place for another distribution, but because it was an LVM partition I was just trying random commands from the internet not knowing what they did which was fairly stupid. I have 3 Logical volumes, `/dev/mapper/vg0-root`, `/dev/mapper/vg0-var` and `/dev/mapper/vg0-home`.

I ended up accidentally running `mke2fs` on my `/dev/mapper/vg0-home` partition, and afterwards I found out that this formatted my partition to an ext2 partition and that I lost all my data.

`Testdisk` didn't find anything because I don't think it can recover files on logical volumes and `vgcfgrestore` didn't result in any luck either.

Answer (score 0):

If you can still login then get a terminal and run `sudo gparted`. If you cannot, which is more likely, make a bootable USB with [gparted](https://gparted.org/livecd.php). It has an `attempt data recovery` under the `Device` menu. This is a very slow process. Backup whatever you can first. You probably only have a 5% chance of recovery I am afraid.

Comment: I think there's a better answer to my question, but let's try your solution first.